# git push - "permission denied"

Tags: git, github, version-control

I'm new to git and github and I'm trying to push to my repository.
I'm currently following github instructions:

```
echo "# test" >> README.md
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git branch -M main
git remote add origin git@github.com:vlocateli/Programming_principles_and_pratice.git
git push -u origin main
```

but when I type

```
git push -u origin main
```

I get the following error:

```
$ git push origin master
Username for 'https://github.com': vlocateli
Password for 'https://vlocateli@github.com': 
remote: Permission to vlocateli/Programming_principles_and_pratice.git denied to vlocateli.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/vlocateli/Programming_principles_and_pratice.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: is `ssh` added, what is the name of upstream branch you want to push to. For github  it is `master`. For gitlab `main`

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same error 2 weeks ago. I uninstalled git from my system and re-installed it. I logged back into my github account and it worked for me. Try doing that.

If that does not work then try the following steps;

1. Do you have a name of the repo? If yes, instead of using the origin, try passing the repo name

> git remote add repo_name url

2. Again, for the final step

> git push repo_name

Comment: I've tried but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is being caused because your remote Git repository does not know about your local repository.

So, you need to set the remote branch as upstream branch of your local branch.

**One liner :** `git push --set-upstream origin master`

So, you want your local main to push to remote `github` `main` repo.

**Detailed**

1. `mkdir custom-project`
2. `cd custom-project`
3. `touch README.md`
4. `git init`
5. `git remote add origin ssh-version-.git`
6. `git add README.md`
7. `git commit -m "initial commit"`
8. `git push --set-upstream origin master`

Comment: When I try to do the detailed one, it gives me this error: ```fatal: 'ssh-version-.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.```

Comment: ssh version means, a ssh link for git, not literally this one